# Android - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file from assets

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse some huge JSON file from assets folder. How can i load and add to RecyclerView. would like to know what is the best approch to parse this kind of big file (about 6MB) and if you may know good API that can help me processing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [GSON lib](https://github.com/google/gson). It has very good performance.

Just add this line in your gradle file to import the lib .

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

If your JSON starts with "[" (array of User let's say), you can use GSON like this :

```
public Set<User> getUsers(final Activity activity) {

    Set<User> usersList = new HashSet<>();
    String json = readFromAsset(activity, "myfile_with_array.json");
    Type listType = new TypeToken<HashSet<User>>() {}.getType();
    // convert json into a list of Users
    try {
        usersList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // we never know :)
        Log.e("error parsing", e.toString());
    }
    return usersList;
}

/**
 * Read file from asset directory
 * @param act current activity
 * @param fileName file to read
 * @return content of the file, string format
 */
private  String readFromAsset(final Activity act, final String fileName)
{
    String text = "";
    try {
        InputStream is = act.getAssets().open(fileName);

        int size = is.available();

        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        text = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

This will return you a set of Users.

If your JSON Starts with a "{", so can be mapped to an object (User object let's say), you can use it like that :

```
public User getUser(final Activity activity) {

        User user = null;
        String json = readFromAsset(activity, "myfile_with_object.json");
        try {
        // convert json in an User object
            user = new Gson.fromJson(json, User.class)
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // we never know :)
            Log.e("error parsing", e.toString());
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: thanks a lot its help me lots, sorry for late reply :)

Comment: In the same way, how to read more than 300 MB file. I got OutofMemory(OOM) error.

Comment: @Vasu Did you find a solution?. Actually my json file is also of 380 MB and I am new to Android development.

Answer (score 1):

Try using google's [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

> Gson Provide simple toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa

It only needs class (that you can even generate online from json [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)) that represents your object and then call:

```
MyObject obj = new Gson.fromJson(jsonString,MyObject.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient way to load a big JSON other than by reading it all and putting it in a JSONObject, unless if the structure is static and you can create a parser for it to read it line by line.

Nonetheless, 6MB is not that large.

Depending on the application and the memory needs, load as many data items as you need in the RecyclerView, then add more if needed. Also, you might load the JSON then null it out when not needed anymore.

String to JSON Object:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I had a 60MB json file, so the best approch is to convert you json data in to SQLite database that you can easily access.

1. Use this site to convert you JSON file to SQLITE, it work for file <100MB https://konbert.com/convert
   (so in case you need to convert larger file use any of these [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407770/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-an-sqlite-database)
2. Once you converted your data you will see that the file size was reduced, mine went from 60MB to 9MB
3. Then put you DB in to you assets folder, and use ROOM DB to access the database you can check this tutorial step by step https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0 or watch some video on Youtube
4. Once you created all you classes for the Database, when you create your database via the 'databaseBuilder', simply use the createFromAsset() method with your database.

   ```
    abstract class CityWeatherDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

         abstract val dao: CityWeatherDao

         companion object {

             @Volatile
             private var INSTANCE: CityWeatherDatabase? = null

             fun getInstance(context: Context): CityWeatherDatabase {
                 synchronized(this) {
                     return INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                         context.applicationContext,
                         CityWeatherDatabase::class.java,
                         "weather"
                     ).createFromAsset("database/weather.db")
                      .build().also {
                         INSTANCE = it
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
   ```

If you use Hilt for dependency injection in your Module file

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCityWeatherDatabase(app: Application): CityWeatherDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            app, CityWeatherDatabase::class.java, "weather"
        ).createFromAsset("database/weather.db") 
            .build()
    }
```