# Is there a way to import data from json file into sqlite where the table column names are different from the key values in the json file?

Tags: json, sqlite

I have a json file which is like { drname : abc,
drtype : mechanical
}

I want to import this to a sqlite table with column names user and department.

I tried everything but it keeps giving various errors.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407770/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-an-sqlite-database.That has complete demonstration of the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a JSON file to an SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407770/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-an-sqlite-database)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Problem solved.