# Reading a large jsonl file into an SQLite database using R

Tags: r, json, sqlite, jsonlite

This is my first question here, please have mercy!

I'm attempting to access Twitter data on a 54GB .jsonl file. I'm no programmer by any means so alternative solutions, advice, or suggestions would be much appreciated.

In my current attempt, I try to stream the file directly into an SQLite database with `stream_in()`.

```
library(DBI)
library(jsonlite)
library(RSQLite)

#I created the sqlite database
tweetdb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "tweet.sqlite")
dbDisconnect(tweetdb)
unlink("tweetdb.sqlite")

#now I'm trying to stream data directly into the database
dbWriteTable(tweetdb, "all_tweets", stream_in(file("all_tweet_ids.jsonl")))
```

The code seems to work but I'm sure there is a better, faster, way to do this. At the moment RStudio says `opening file input connection. Found 870000 records...` after going up to about 720000 records quite fast, it got stuck at that number for about an hour, then going to 870000 where it's stuck again now.

My end goal here is to have a database, data.frame, data.table, or any representation of the data so that I can access parts of it, construct subsets, manipulate it, and work with it. An SQL database would be desirable - I believe - because I'm working on a MacBook and I don't have access to any more computing power. I'm working towards a text analysis of those tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you're running into memory problems. Because you're using `stream_in`, I will assume (and this is a requirement for this answer) that the data is in ndjson format (newline-delimited json). With this, you can split the file into multiple smaller files (perhaps just to two files) and then read them in individually, allowing garbage-collection (memory management) to work.

The command-line (not R) `split` will split a text file into multiple files. It's available on every linux system I've seen; on windows, it is within Git for Windows; and I found it on my mac (though I don't do R dev on it).

I'll start with a simple 10-line ndjson file:

```r
dat <- data.frame(num=1:10)
jsonlite::stream_out(dat) # this will be the single file's contents
# {"num":1}
# {"num":2}
# {"num":3}
# {"num":4}
# {"num":5}
# {"num":6}
# {"num":7}
# {"num":8}
# {"num":9}
# {"num":10}
# Complete! Processed total of 10 rows.

jsonlite::stream_out(dat, file("quux.ndjson"))
# opening file output connection.
# Complete! Processed total of 10 rows.
# closing file output connection.
```

Now I can split that file into (in this case) two files:

```r
list.files(pattern = "^quux.")
# [1] "quux.ndjson"
system2("split", c("--lines", "8", "quux.ndjson", "quux.ndjson."))
list.files(pattern = "^quux.")
# [1] "quux.ndjson"    "quux.ndjson.aa" "quux.ndjson.ab"
system2("wc", c("-l", list.files(pattern = "^quux.")))
#  10 quux.ndjson
#   8 quux.ndjson.aa
#   2 quux.ndjson.ab
#  20 total
```

About `split`:

- `--lines` is the max number of lines in a single file. In your case, you may want 500000 or so, but smaller shouldn't hurt.
- the first `quux.ndjson` is the input file name
- the second `quux.ndjson.` (note the trailing `.`) is the prefix to use for output files; if you don't provide this, then the files will be named `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, ... this was mostly for aesthetics, use whatever prefix you prefer

I then ran `wc -l` just to show the number of lines per file. Not required, just demonstrative. We can further demonstrate the split with

```r
readLines("quux.ndjson.ab")
# [1] "{\"num\":9}"  "{\"num\":10}"
```

From here, you should be able to iterate over the files and do whatever you want, perhaps

```r
# note the updated pattern
for (fn in list.files(pattern = "^quux.ndjson.")) {
  dbWriteTable(tweetdb, "all_tweets", stream_in(file(fn)))
}
```

(untested).

Since I don't have "large-ish" data to test with, here's a thought: depending on how often you perform this, you *might* consider calling `gc()` between each `stream_in`. While it is automatic and should handle things itself, I wonder if this will have any impact on your process. `gc` will force garbage-collection, de-allocating unreferenced objects. I think it is not necessary, but just a thought.

Comment: btw, there is a non-R method that uses `jq` (a very efficient command-line json parsing tool) to convert to CSV and import natively with SQLite's csv-import. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407771/3358272. There might be reason to do it in R (perhaps you need to subset or otherwise influence the data before import), but if R is meant merely as a facilitator, then consider the `jq` solution as another efficient method. (It's likely faster, too.)