# How do I store the json file in sqlite database and connect with Flask API?

Tags: json, sqlite, flask

My jsonfile looks somewhat like:

```
{ 
  "names":["38"], 
  "metadata": [ 
    { "id": 38, "Lat": 32, "Long":32 }
  ], "samples": [ 
    { "id":"38", "date":[ "5/5/2016", "9/5/2016" ], "values":[ 11.42, 11.37 ] }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at PickleType of SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Not Yet. Will have a look now. Thanks

Comment: Also if you are not comfortable with working with PickleType here is a link of the same question as you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603621/how-to-store-json-object-in-sqlite-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407770/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-an-sqlite-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a dict as a JSON response from a Flask view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/how-to-return-a-dict-as-a-json-response-from-a-flask-view)