# How to go about parsing a large JSON file for search bar suggestions

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a 29mb [JSON](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz) containing cities of the the world for a weather app.

This is the JSON structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1283378,
    "name": "Gorkhā",
    "country": "NP",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 84.633331,
      "lat": 28
    }
  },
...
]
```

I have a Fragment that contains a list of saved cities and a fab that prompts a alert dialog with a textfield where the user is supposed to type the city name and get suggestions from the parsed data.

My problem is that parsing this file is eating a lot of memory and slowing the user xp (even though it is running on a different thread the fab is disabled until the operation is done).
Parsing the file each time the user accesses the cities fragment seems stupid so is keeping the result object in memory, 
so i guess my question is how should i approach this??

Using GSON like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074381/android-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file-from-assets) thread or [this](https://computersciencegeeks.wordpress.com/2017/08/16/read-large-json-files-using-gson/) article suggests is great but it doesn't tackle the repetitive nature of the problem.

```java
public static List<City> getCitiesFromJSON(Context context){
    List<City> cityList = new LinkedList<>();
    try{
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("jsons/city.list.min.json");
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        reader.beginArray();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        while (reader.hasNext()){
            City cityJson = gson.fromJson(reader, City.class);
            City city = new City();
            city.setId(cityJson.getId());
            city.setName(cityJson.getName());
            city.setCountry(cityJson.getCountry());
            city.setCoord(new Coord(cityJson.getCoord().getLon(),cityJson.getCoord().getLat()));
            cityList.add(city);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cityList;
}
```

**tl;dr**

Need to parse big JSON for search suggestions each time the user tries to add to a list, but that operation is both memory and time consuming so i need a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**: A better approach is to request the JSON in background as soon as the app starts up and saving it to a Local storage(SQlite, Room Persistence or just sharedpreference).

**Approach 2:** The second trick is to show only a large enough number but not to large. 
Suppose user there are 1000 results matching the string of user input. Just query the local or remote database to show best matching 100. No sane person will scroll past 100 results without modifying/writing his input text again.

**Best Approach:** Use a pagination library to load data as the user scrolls down.

Comment: I'm accepting this answers since the first approach is what I've [implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810513/2708277)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case loading the cities in memory (Singleton Object) is better ,
or if the target client resources/ram will be affected then you will need to have a remote server for doing the work either a search engine (like ElasticSearch ) or a rest application that will do the processing and caching

Plus that caching the search requests will help in preventing the redundant processing .

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how I went about solving this:**

- Used Room to handle database operations:

City entity:

```java
@Entity
public class City {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    @Embedded
    private Coord coord;

    public City(){

    }

    public City(JSONObject json){
        this.id = json.optLong("id");
        this.name = json.optString("name");
        this.country = json.optString("country");
        this.coord = new Coord(json.optJSONObject("coord"));
    }

    public City(long id, String name, String country, Coord coord) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

City DAO:

```java
@Dao
public interface CityDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM city")
    List<City> getAll();

    // Used to query search suggestions
    @Query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE name LIKE :name || '%' ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 10")
    City findByName(String name);

    // Used to determine whether or not the db was created
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM city")
    int getCitySize();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(City... cities);

    @Insert
    void insertCity(City city);

    @Delete
    void deleteCity(City city);

    @Query("DELETE FROM city")
    public void nukeCities();
}
```

AppDatabase:

```java
@Database(entities = {City.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract CityDao cityDao();
}
```

- In the Application class I implemented a Runnable with a callback that upon parsing the JSON and populating the db starts the countdown of a CountDownLatch(used by the AddCityFragment to enable the fab)

Application:

```java
public class App extends Application implements RunnableCompleteListener {
    private final CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private AppDatabase appDB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appDB = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "cities-db").build();

        NotifyingRunnable readCitiesJSON = new NotifyingRunnable() {
            List<City> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public void doRun() {
                int dbCitySize = appDB.cityDao().getCitySize();
                // if db is empty
                if (dbCitySize == 0){
                    citiesList = HelperFunctions.getCitiesFromJSON(getApplicationContext());
                    appDB.cityDao().insertAll(citiesList.toArray(new City[citiesList.size()]));
                }
            }
        };
        readCitiesJSON.addListener(this);
        Thread worker = new Thread(readCitiesJSON);
        worker.start();
    }

    public AppDatabase getDatabase() {
        return appDB;
    }

    public CountDownLatch getStartLatch() {
        return startLatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyOfRunnableComplete(Runnable runnable) {
        startLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Runnable implementation:

```java
public interface RunnableCompleteListener {
    void notifyOfRunnableComplete(final Runnable runnable);
}

public abstract class NotifyingRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Set<RunnableCompleteListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<RunnableCompleteListener>();

    public final void addListener(final RunnableCompleteListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public final void removeListener(final RunnableCompleteListener listener){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private final void notifyListeners(){
        for(RunnableCompleteListener listener : listeners){
            listener.notifyOfRunnableComplete(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        try{
            doRun();
        }finally {
            notifyListeners();
        }
    }

    public abstract void doRun();
}
```

- Changed getCitiesFromJSON to treat the json as an object no need for stream access since i'll be using the database for that

```java
    public static List<City> getCitiesFromJSON(Context context){
        String json = "";
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("jsons/city.list.min.json");
            int size = is.available();

            // read the entire asset into a local buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<City> citiesList = new ArrayList<City>();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<City>>() {}.getType();

        // convert json into a list of cities
        try {
            citiesList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error parsing", e.toString());
        }
        return citiesList;
    }
```

- Finally inside the onCreateView of the fragment a thread waits for the latch to count down in order to enable the fab

```java
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        fabAddCity = view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddCity);
        fabAddCity.setOnClickListener(this);
        // disabled by default
        fabAddCity.setEnabled(false);
        fabAddCity.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        // the thread that controls the fab state
        Thread fabController = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                ((App)getActivity().getApplication()).getStartLatch().await();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    fabAddCity.setEnabled(true);
                    fabAddCity.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        fabController.start();
        ...
    }
```